# ORA-01422 - exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows error

Tags: plsql, ora-01422

I am a newbie in writing PL/SQL. I have this small code, but unable to print out the output due to the subject error.

```
declare
output_tour_id varchar(4000);

begin
dbms_output.enable;

for r in 
(
SELECT TOUR_ID FROM "/DSD/HH_RADELHD"
VERSIONS BETWEEN TIMESTAMP TO_TIMESTAMP('2015-04-02 18:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD    HH24:MI:SS')
AND TO_TIMESTAMP('2015-04-02 18:30:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
WHERE VERSIONS_OPERATION = 'D'
group by VERSIONS_STARTTIME, CLIENT, TOUR_ID
) 

Loop
@/tmp/get.sql r.tour_id;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (output_tour_id);
end loop;
end;
/
```

I get this error after executing:

```
old  30: WHERE CLIENT = 100 and TOUR_ID = &1;
new  30: WHERE CLIENT = 100 and TOUR_ID = r.tour_id;
'100','100002039690','000001','0001398563','0050543675','10','C170','20150402070750','CET','1',' ','10',' ','91597','20150330',' ',
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512: at line 13
```

Your inputs would be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

How do I make my code execute properly?

Comment: Where are you populating `output_tour_id`?

Comment: @mmmmmmmpie, it is populating inside the get.sql script; the script does a select into variable `output_tour_id`.

Comment: So how does your anonymous block know the contents of `output_tour_id`?

Answer (score 0):

The error is in your *get.sql* script. Your `SELECT INTO` statement in this script returns more than 1 row. You can try to use `SELECT DISTINCT` and/or add another `WHERE` condition to restrict the result set.

Comment: Thank you @Pavel Gatnar. The get.sql is meant to retrieve many rows. I thought that the variable will store each row and then be displayed by `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (output_tour_id);`, then gets updated again on the next loop with the new value from `r.tour_id`.